# typescript react style conditional with 2 conditions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a conditional for styling that works with only one condition:

```
<View
          style={[
            message.sender.isSystem && styles.systemMessageLine,
            message.data.mine && styles.yourMessageLine,
          ]}
>
```

Now if I want to have 2 conditionals how will I format that?

```
    <View
          style={[
            (!message.data.mine && !message.sender.isSystem) && styles.thirdPartyMessage
          ]}
    >
```

is the operator

> &&

valid to concatenate 2 conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the operator `&&` valid to concatenate 2 conditions?

Yes.

Also your formatting is correct